# Play one song at a time in HTML5

Tags: jquery, html, audio, html5-audio

I'm making a html5 site with many audio elements and I want them to be played one at a time, in order to do this I used jQuery to pause and play the song.

I found a code here that allow me to do that but the thread it's been dead for 2 years.

The problem come when I play a song, let's call it song1, then pause it and then try to play song1 again, the song1 doesn't start to reproduce, in order to play song1 again I have to reproduce any other song and then click song1 one again so it can start to play. I'm not sure of how to fix this. How can I make it to play without doing this?

Many thanks in advance.

HTML:

```
<div id="song">
    <a class="playback">
        <img class="play" src="./MusicPlayer/base.png" />
    </a>
    <audio><source src="./MusicPlayer/avicii.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" /></audio>
</div>
<div id="song2" >
    <a class="playback">
        <img class="play" src="./MusicPlayer/base.png" />
    </a>
    <audio><source src="./MusicPlayer/harlem.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" /></audio>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var curPlaying;
$(function () {
    $(".playback").click(function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var song = $(this).next('audio')[0];
       if (song.paused) {
           song.play();
           if (curPlaying) {
               $("audio", "#" + curPlaying)[0].pause();
           }
       } else {
           song.pause();
       }
       curPlaying = $(this).parent()[0].id;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var curPlaying;
$(function () {
    $(".playback").click(function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var song = $(this).next('audio')[0];
       if (song.paused) {
           if (curPlaying) {
               $("audio", "#" + curPlaying)[0].pause();
           }
           song.play();
           curPlaying = $(this).parent()[0].id;
       } else {
           song.pause();
           curPlaying = null;
       }
    });
});
```

The problem was this flow:

1) Play song 1 (curPlaying == song1)

2) Pause song1 (curPlaying is *still* set to song1)

3) Play song1 (because curPlaying is still truthy, song1 immediately gets paused)

Anyway, it's pretty late and i'm drained, so my code might not actually work (oops). But hopefully the rest of the answer will get you on the right track.